# How to remove image from QTextEdit

Tags: qtextedit, pyqt6

I add images to QTextEdit as shown below using pytq6.
How do I remove the inserted image, and/or their resource?

```
document = text_edit.document()
image = QtGui.QImageReader(path_).read()  # QImage
url = QtCore.QUrl(imagename)    
document.addResource(QtGui.QTextDocument.ResourceType.ImageResource.value, url, image)
cursor = text_edit.textCursor()
image_format = QtGui.QTextImageFormat()
image_format.setName(url.toString())
cursor.insertImage(image_format)
```

Comment: It depends, but for general usage you can just select the text containing the image (it's just a character, so move the cursor to the beginning and then go to the next character), then call [`removeSelectedText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#removeSelectedText). This will obviously add a further action in the undo stack.

Comment: Brilliant. Yes that works perfectly now, I can delete the image and insert another one.

Comment: Wait, did you ask that because you wanted to replace the image?

Comment: Yes that was the reason. But just replacing the resource did not work because the width and height did not change (i tried to fo this). So now remove old inage and insert new image is perfect. For full information the user can rotate the image via a context menu. The text edit can be full of text and images, it is a results report.

Comment: Ok, if it's done after use interaction then it's fine. I thought that you wanted to replace the actual resource in a way that was transparent to the user (so, without completely affecting the undo stack), which would be theoretically possible, but a bit tricky to achieve. Note that, since you want to actually replace the image, you don't need to remove the text, but just replace the selection using [`insertImage()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#insertImage-2).